# Mouse on / mouse off (hover) issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have 2 buttons

Button 1 (blue) button2 (orange)

When I hover over button 1 it becomes orange and when I hover off it becomes blue again same with orange OK

Now I want it when I hover over button 1 (blue) button 2 must be blue and button 1 must be orange and when I mousoout of it it must return to button 1 (blue) and buttons 2 (orange)

with my CSS and JavaScript Script! I've been struggling all day I'm very new to web coding!

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  "use strict";
  $('#slider-carousel').carouFredSel({
    responsive: true,
    width: '100%',
    circular: true,
    scroll: {
      item: 1,
      duration: 500,
      pauseOnHover: true
    },
    auto: true,
    items: {
      visible: {
        min: 1,
        max: 1
      },
      height: "variable"
    },
    pagination: {
      container: ".sliderpager",
      pageAnchorBuilder: false
    }

  });
});

$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".slider a.btn-half").mouseover(function() {
    $(".slider a.btn-full").css("background-color", "deepskyblue");
  });
});
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".slider a.btn-half").mouseout(function() {
    $(".slider a.btn-full").css("background-color", "orange");
  });
});
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".slider a.btn-full").mouseover(function() {
    $(".slider a.btn-half").css("background-color", "deepskyblue");
  });
});
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".slider a.btn-half").mouseout(function() {
    $(".slider a.btn-full").css("background-color", "orange");
  });
});
```

```css
*,
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

header {
  background-color: deepskyblue;
  height: 112px;
  line-height: 112px;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
}

ul li {
  display: inline-block;
}

header nav {
  float: right;
}

header nav ul li a {
  padding-right: 30px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: white;
  transition: 0.5s ease-in;
}

header nav ul li a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: orange;
}

.img1 {
  background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7)), url(https://via.placeholder.com/50);
  background-size: 100% 100%;
}

.slider,
.slider ul,
.slider ul li {
  height: 700px;
  width: 100%;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}

.slider h2 {
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-top: 220px;
}

.slider span {
  color: orange;
}

.slider a {
  padding: 10px 50px;
  ;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.slider a.btn-half {
  background-color: deepskyblue;
  color: white;
  transition: 0.5s ease-in;
}

.slider a.btn-half:hover {
  opacity: 0.7;
  color: deepskyblue;
  background-color: orange;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-style: italic;
}

.slider a.btn-full {
  background-color: orange;
  color: white;
  transition: 0.5s ease-in;
}

.slider a.btn-full:hover {
  opacity: 0.7;
  color: orange;
  background-color: deepskyblue;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-style: italic;
}

.img2 {
  background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7)), url(https://via.placeholder.com/50);
  background-size: 100% 100%;
}

.img3 {
  background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7)), url(https://via.placeholder.com/50);
  background-size: 100% 100%;
}

.slider i {
  font-size: 35px;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>

  <title>Latinas Enteprises</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.caroufredsel/6.2.1/jquery.carouFredSel.packed.js"></script>

  <script src="js/caroufredsel.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <header>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <a href="" class="logo"><img src="img/Logo2.png"></a>
        <nav>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Services</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Gallery </a></li>
            <li><a href="">Contact</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Our Team</a></li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
      </div>
    </div>
  </header>
  <section class="slider">
    <ul class="slidr-carousel" id="slider-carousel">
      <li class="img1">
        <h2>LATINAS <span>ENTERPRISES</span></h2>
        <p>We Believe In Creativity Always</p>
        <i class="fa fa-scissors"></i>
        <i class="fa fa-female"></i>
        <i class="fa fa-pencil"></i>
        <p><br> A brush of perfection!

        </p><br>
        <a href="" class="btn btn-half">Get Started</a>
        <a href="" class="btn btn-full">Call us Now!</a>
      </li>
      <li class="img2">
        <h2>LATINAS <span>ENTERPRISES</span></h2>
        <p>We Believe In Creativity Always</p>
        <i class="fa fa-scissors"></i>
        <i class="fa fa-female"></i>
        <i class="fa fa-pencil"></i>
        <p><br> A brush of perfection!

        </p><br>
        <a href="" class="btn btn-half">Get Started</a>
        <a href="" class="btn btn-full">Call us Now!</a>
      </li>
      <li class="img3">
        <h2>LATINAS <span>ENTERPRISES</span></h2>
        <p>We Believe In Creativity Always</p>
        <i class="fa fa-scissors"></i>
        <i class="fa fa-female"></i>
        <i class="fa fa-pencil"></i>
        <p><br> A brush of perfection!

        </p><br>
        <a href="" class="btn btn-half">Get Started</a>
        <a href="" class="btn btn-full">Call us Now!</a>
      </li>
    </ul>

  </section>
  <script src="js/main.js"></script>

</body>


</html>
```

Comment: Your code seems to work fine. To understand your question correctly when hovering over first button you want to reverse colors and then when mouse out you want to return to original state?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this work for you?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".slider a.btn-half").mouseover(function() {
    $(".slider a.btn-full").css("background-color", "deepskyblue")
    $(".slider a.btn-half").css("background-color", "orange");
  });
});

$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".slider a.btn-half").mouseout(function() {
    $(".slider a.btn-full").css("background-color", "orange");
    $(".slider a.btn-half").css("background-color", "deepskyblue");
  });
});

$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".slider a.btn-full").mouseover(function() {
    $(".slider a.btn-full").css("background-color", "deepskyblue");
    $(".slider a.btn-half").css("background-color", "orange");
  });
});

$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".slider a.btn-full").mouseout(function() {
    $(".slider a.btn-full").css("background-color", "orange");
    $(".slider a.btn-half").css("background-color", "deepskyblue");
  });
});
```

Just replace your functions with these ones

Comment: Thanks This is what i wanted it works please explain what i did wrong so i can learn thanks

Answer (score 0):

You don't need jQuery to do this. You can achieve this with CSS only using  the "+" selector. I have commented out the unnecessary JS code. Then you can add this CSS:

```
.slider a.btn-half:hover + a.btn-full
{
  background-color: deepskyblue;
}
```

See this example:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  "use strict";
  $('#slider-carousel').carouFredSel({
    responsive: true,
    width: '100%',
    circular: true,
    scroll: {
      item: 1,
      duration: 5000,
      pauseOnHover: true
    },
    auto: true,
    items: {
      visible: {
        min: 1,
        max: 1
      },
      height: "variable"
    },
    pagination: {
      container: ".sliderpager",
      pageAnchorBuilder: false
    }

  });
});
/*
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".slider a.btn-half").mouseover(function() {
    $(".slider a.btn-full").css("background-color", "deepskyblue");
  });
});
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".slider a.btn-half").mouseout(function() {
    $(".slider a.btn-full").css("background-color", "orange");
  });
});
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".slider a.btn-full").mouseover(function() {
    $(".slider a.btn-half").css("background-color", "deepskyblue");
  });
});
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".slider a.btn-half").mouseout(function() {
    $(".slider a.btn-full").css("background-color", "orange");
  });
});
*/
```

```css
*,
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

header {
  background-color: deepskyblue;
  height: 112px;
  line-height: 112px;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
}

ul li {
  display: inline-block;
}

header nav {
  float: right;
}

header nav ul li a {
  padding-right: 30px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: white;
  transition: 0.5s ease-in;
}

header nav ul li a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: orange;
}

.img1 {
  background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7)), url(https://via.placeholder.com/50);
  background-size: 100% 100%;
}

.slider,
.slider ul,
.slider ul li {
  height: 700px;
  width: 100%;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}

.slider h2 {
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-top: 220px;
}

.slider span {
  color: orange;
}

.slider a {
  padding: 10px 50px;
  ;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.slider a.btn-half {
  background-color: deepskyblue;
  color: white;
  transition: 0.5s ease-in;
}

.slider a.btn-half:hover {
  opacity: 0.7;
  color: deepskyblue;
  background-color: orange;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-style: italic;
}

/* Add this css */
.slider a.btn-half:hover + a.btn-full
{
  background-color: deepskyblue;
}



.slider a.btn-full {
  background-color: orange;
  color: white;
  transition: 0.5s ease-in;
}

.slider a.btn-full:hover {
  opacity: 0.7;
  color: orange;
  background-color: deepskyblue;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-style: italic;
}

.img2 {
  background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7)), url(https://via.placeholder.com/50);
  background-size: 100% 100%;
}

.img3 {
  background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7)), url(https://via.placeholder.com/50);
  background-size: 100% 100%;
}

.slider i {
  font-size: 35px;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>

  <title>Latinas Enteprises</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.caroufredsel/6.2.1/jquery.carouFredSel.packed.js"></script>

  <script src="js/caroufredsel.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <header>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <a href="" class="logo"><img src="img/Logo2.png"></a>
        <nav>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Services</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Gallery </a></li>
            <li><a href="">Contact</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Our Team</a></li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
      </div>
    </div>
  </header>
  <section class="slider">
    <ul class="slidr-carousel" id="slider-carousel">
      <li class="img1">
        <h2>LATINAS <span>ENTERPRISES</span></h2>
        <p>We Believe In Creativity Always</p>
        <i class="fa fa-scissors"></i>
        <i class="fa fa-female"></i>
        <i class="fa fa-pencil"></i>
        <p><br> A brush of perfection!

        </p><br>
        <a href="" class="btn btn-half">Get Started</a>
        <a href="" class="btn btn-full">Call us Now!</a>
      </li>
      <li class="img2">
        <h2>LATINAS <span>ENTERPRISES</span></h2>
        <p>We Believe In Creativity Always</p>
        <i class="fa fa-scissors"></i>
        <i class="fa fa-female"></i>
        <i class="fa fa-pencil"></i>
        <p><br> A brush of perfection!

        </p><br>
        <a href="" class="btn btn-half">Get Started</a>
        <a href="" class="btn btn-full">Call us Now!</a>
      </li>
      <li class="img3">
        <h2>LATINAS <span>ENTERPRISES</span></h2>
        <p>We Believe In Creativity Always</p>
        <i class="fa fa-scissors"></i>
        <i class="fa fa-female"></i>
        <i class="fa fa-pencil"></i>
        <p><br> A brush of perfection!

        </p><br>
        <a href="" class="btn btn-half">Get Started</a>
        <a href="" class="btn btn-full">Call us Now!</a>
      </li>
    </ul>

  </section>
  <script src="js/main.js"></script>

</body>


</html>
```